shortcut for pasting text into single line?
I love how vscode always asks me "are you sure that you want to paste content of multiple line into terminal", and gives me the option of pasting into single line (see graph for example). But today I got a litte tipsy and clicked on "don't ask me again" when I saw the dialog. Now I don't know how to paste contents of multiple lines as a single line into terminal...
Yes, I can paste it into a seperated txt and remove the lines but is there any way to bring back the dialog, or is there a shortcut to paste into single line?
pic 1
I want to bring back the dialog, but am clueless so far as to what I can do...

Look in your settings.json and delete or comment this setting (which is probably near the end of the file):
"terminal.integrated.enableMultiLinePasteWarning": false,

The relevant setting is
Terminal > Integrated: Enable Multi Line Paste Warning

so usually you could just go there and reset it to auto (the default) but there seems to be a bug that prevents doing that in this case.  So remove the setting in your settings.json instead.
